# which is better popupcontrolextender or modalpopupextender

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to use popup, i found two different control in ajaxtoolkit,
1- PopupControlExtender 
2- ModalPopupExtender

can you tell me which one have a better performance?
and what is the difference between those?

thanks a lot

Comment: "which is better" is not a good question to ask.  Difference between the two is ok.

Comment: These are two different ajax control toolkit controls! Check out http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx and http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx

Comment: @BlackICE why this is not a good question?? certainly one of these controls have a better performance, or work More accurate.

Comment: He says it is "not a good question" because the answer is subjective and prone to opinion and not fact. However, I got the impression that it was people's opinions that you wanted ;]

Comment: I want to know, in people's experiences, which of them works better? and has least problem. ?

Comment: I don't ask, which is better RED or BLUE? My question is not opinion base, not at all. I ask about performance and optimum of two Controls. please be careful

Answer (score 2):

I can't directly answer your question as to which is better. But from my experience I'd leave the AjaxToolkit well alone (unless of course there are other requirements/constraints that force you to use it).

When I need a modal popup I either code some jQuery myself or use jQueryUI Dialog

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I'm not saying that AjaxToolkit should never be used. It is my opinion that jquery UI is a much better framework. I personally NEVER use the AjaxToolkit, but each to their own.

EDIT: I don't like the AjaxToolkit becaue:
1) I don't like having server side markup control client side scripting. I would rather just write the client side script myself.
2) I don't like all of the ScriptResource.axd requests that get fired from the page. I'd prefer to have just one 'big' js file and compress/cache it.
3) I don't like update panels, they cause all sorts of problems with viewstate etc. I'd prefer to just write simple 'Web Methods' and call them over ajax with jQuery.

Comment: would help to say why you would leave AjaxToolkit alone